# Overriding all properties similar to !important

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to override every style property using a method similar to the !important declaration.

I want to override all properties without changing the order of the loaded stylesheets.

I'm also not able to change different stylesheets

**EDIT**

Might there be a way to put !important on an element?

Comment: You haven't explained why `!important` won't suit your needs.

Comment: Why "similar to the !important"? Can't you use `!important`?

Comment: Override all properties where exactly? On a single element, or in a custom CSS rule, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be more specific in your styles.

For example, if you had HTML like this:

```
<div id="greg">
  <p class="likes">
    Hello, something <span class="toast">more</span>.
  </p>
</div>
```

This:

```
span{
  color:red;
}
```

would be over written by this:

```
#greg .likes .toast{
  color:blue;
}
```

Instead of slapping `!important` everywhere, just make your styles more specific.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jpf5/)**

---

Alternatively, if you can't actually edit the CSS file, you could always try `inline` styles, although they're harder to overwrite and shouldn't REALLY be done unless 100% necessary or you're applying styles through javascript etc...

example:

```
<div style="color:red">Caterpillar</div>
```

Comment: I guess you aren't supposed to do what i want. I will just have to learn how to use more specific selectors. Thanks anyways

Comment: @MeneerVenus That is more or less probably correct for your situation.  Whatever is causing you to need to do this probably isn't semantically "good" in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use weight of css selectors.

Good article by [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

So you can increase the weight of your selectors using body tag for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5CqyH/).

```
div {
    background: red;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
body div {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: he said he's not able to change stylesheets...

Answer (score -1):

the only way to do it would be to apply a !important style tag to the element in itself since this would then take preference over the style sheet declaration.
with simple html:

```
<p id="foo" style="color: blue!important;">LOREM IPSUM</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/5KbGV/

With JS:

```
$('#foo').attr('style', 'color:green!important');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/5KbGV/6/

Comment: @beatalex makes a very good point though !important should be the very last option always.

Comment: This is not applying important to an element...

Comment: yes it is the text in that fiddle is green which is applyied by the jquery...